# Me gustaría saber que mas condiciones tengo que agregarle a mi "if" para que pueda reconocer un numero cuando este es impar o cuando no lo es

Tags: autonumeric

Esto es lo que yo he intentado hacer pero desafortunadamente aun no esta correcto del todo ya que le hacen falta mas condiciones al "if"[Ejercicio que intente resolver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EQB9.jpg)[image: Teoria de cuando un numero es primo]

Comment: Por favor adjunta el código, si deseas adjuntar código, pegalo en la pregunta, selecciónalo, y presiona `Ctrl + K`. Saludos

Comment: Para tu código, no necesitas ninguna otra condición para saber si es par o no, con la comprobación del resto que estas haciendo es suficiente, por otro lado, si lo que quieres es saber si el numero es primo o no, lo que haces no es correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Número primo y número impar son dos cosas diferentes.
Para saber si es un número impar, solo tiene que dividirlo por dos y comprobar que el resto no sea 0.
Para comprobar que sea primo tendrías que comprobar todas las probabilidades del número, o hacer una tabla de datos con todos los número primos conocidos, lo cual sería un problema muy grande.

Answer (score 0):

Para calcular si un número es primo, primero aplicamos algunos descartes, para acelerar el proceso:

- 1, 2 y 3 son primos.
- Cualquier valor par no es primo.

Si pasa estas dos pruebas, revisaremos si el número es divisible por algún entero impar menor que él. Si es un compuesto, uno de los dos factores tendrá que ser menor o igual a la raíz cuadrada del número. La raíz cuadrada es costosa de calcular, por lo que simplemente buscare hasta N / 2.

```
def primo(n):
    if n < 4:
        return True
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    limite = ceil(n / 2) + 1

    for i in range(3, limite, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False

    return True
```

**Comprobación**

Obtuve esta lista de números primos:

```
primos = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

que usare para comprobar todos los valores hasta 99:

Primero evaluare la función `primo` contra la lista. Todos los resultados deben dar `True`, lo que puedo verificar con la función `all`.

La función `all` recibe un iterable y retorna `True` si todos lo son.

```
if all([primo(i) for i in primos]):
    print("Todos primos")
```

Luego evaluare los valores que no están en la lista de primos, para detectar falsos positivos:

```
if all([not primo(i) for i in range(4, 100) if i not in primos]):
    print("Ninguno es primo")
```

El resultado es:

```
Todos primos
Ninguno es primo
```

Q.E.D.